# In what order does a minheap sort?

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, data-structures, heap

I've been reading various definitions on minHeap and maxHeap. I stumbled upon statements which say:

1. minHeap is used to sort in descending order.
2. maxHeap is used to sort in ascending order.

Statements taken from the "Note" in https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/heap-sort-for-decreasing-order-using-min-heap/ .
But when I implement minHeap using `PriorityQueue<Integer>` in Java with default comparator, and poll() it, I get the minimum element. Why is that?
Thanks to anybody who's trying to help :).

Comment: Where are you quoting from? The idea of a min heap is to efficiently access the minimal value, doing so repeatedly cannot, it seems, result in ascending order.

Comment: @Yunnosch https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/heap-sort-for-decreasing-order-using-min-heap/ ...Checkout the "Note" in this

Comment: Please [edit] to provide that information directly inside your question, instead of hiding it down here in the comments.

Comment: @Yunnosch Done..Have any idea which is the right one?

Comment: I read the link, you seem to be quoting/summarizing correctly. I am looking forward to seeing an explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

min-heap and max-heap don't sort. You can use a min-heap or max-heap to sort, but in standard use, heaps aren't sorted. Instead, they arranged in what's called heap order. This arrangement makes it efficient to add items, and to remove the smallest (or largest) while keeping the data in the proper order.

For example, here's an illustration of a min-heap:

```
                1
            3       2
          4   7   6   5
```

That follows the rule that no child is larger than its parent. The resulting array representation of that heap is `[1,3,2,4,7,6,5]`. Note that there are other valid heaps with those same numbers. For example, both of the below are valid, as well:

```
                1                          1
            2       5                  2       3
          4   3   6   7              4   5   6   7
```

The corresponding array representations are `[1,2,5,4,3,6,7]` and `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]`.

Max-heap is similar, except the rule is that no child can be larger than its parent.

The [Wikipedia article on binary heap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_heap) explains this all very well.

Now, when you're talking about using heap sort, you build a heap and then repeatedly swap the root element with the last element in the array, reduce the count and then re-heapify. So you build the sorted array from back to front. If you use a min-heap, then the root (smallest value) will be at the end of the array.

So if you want to sort in descending order with heap sort, you use a min-heap.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation :)

Answer (score 2):

The explanation in the blog is correct

While having a close look at the `heapSort()` function, it has smartly made use of min heap. The smallest element of the array gets replaced with the last element and size of heap is reduced by 1 to again `heapify()` it.

`arr[0]` -> represents the smallest element.

In every iteration, for `i` from `n-1` to `0`, the arr[0] is swapped with the `arr[i]`  and heap is again heapified with size of 1 smaller than previous iteration.

Comment: why do we need to do that?Can't we just poll the 0 index and heapify from 1 to n?

Comment: Queue has not been used. Array has been used. So, the best the author could do, is to swap the element at index 0 with the last one and heapify. This is kind of polling itself by swaping

Comment: Thank you..But forget the article...In what order does minHeap sort generally(not in the article)?

Answer (score 0):

The basic idea is to sort in place. Every time the algorithm polls from the heap, the heaps size shrinks by one. So one place at the end of the array is not part of the heap anymore. In this index the n-th smallest number is placed.

```
// One by one extract an element from heap 
for (int i = n - 1; i >= 0; i--) { 
    // Move current root to end 
    swap(arr[0], arr[i]); 

    // call max heapify on the reduced heap 
    heapify(arr, i, 0); 
}
```

So the explanation why your algorithm using a `PriorityQueue` behaves so oddly is that you use a separate array for output. You could either switch to a max-heap and stick to your approach or fill the output-array in reverse. Both should produce the same behavior.